# ratio math not working with std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I don't understand `std::chrono::duration`.

I'm trying to calculate a future timepoint based on a video frame rate. I need to do the same again (and again) once that timepoint has been reached.

Like this:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
typedef duration<int, std::ratio<1,10>> TenFPS_t;
typedef duration<int, std::ratio<1001,30000>> NTSC_FPS_t;
// this compiles ok
time_point<steady_clock> compiles (time_point<steady_clock>& ref, int frames) {
return ref + TenFPS_t(frames);
}
// this one, when uncommented spits out many complaints
time_point<steady_clock> wontCompile (time_point<steady_clock>& ref, int frames) {
return ref + NTSC_FPS_t(frames);
}
```

I guess the issue is that 30,000 / 1,001 isn't an integer number of nanoseconds which is (I think) the resolution of the `std::chrono::steady_clock` I'm using. So I need to pick the nearest integer to the frame period and accumulate errors to feed into the calculation for the next one. Am I right?

Compiler error follows:

```
$ g++ -Wall -ggdb -std=gnu++0x -fPIC example.cpp  -c -o example.o
example.cpp:12:9: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
      'time_point<[...], duration<[...], ratio<[...], __static_lcm<ratio<1,
      1000000000>::den, ratio<1001, 24000>::den>::value aka 3000000000>>>' to
      function return type 'time_point<[...], duration<[...], ratio<[...],
      1000000000>>>'
        return ref + NTSC_FPS_t(frames);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:831:28: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, typename
      common_type<duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000000000> >, duration<int,
      ratio<1001, 24000> > >::type>' (aka
      'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, duration<long long,
      ratio<__static_gcd<ratio<1, 1000000000>::num, ratio<1001,
      24000>::num>::value, __static_lcm<ratio<1, 1000000000>::den, ratio<1001,
      24000>::den>::value> > >') to 'const
      std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock,
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >
      &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS time_point
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:831:28: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, typename
      common_type<duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000000000> >, duration<int,
      ratio<1001, 24000> > >::type>' (aka
      'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, duration<long long,
      ratio<__static_gcd<ratio<1, 1000000000>::num, ratio<1001,
      24000>::num>::value, __static_lcm<ratio<1, 1000000000>::den, ratio<1001,
      24000>::den>::value> > >') to
      'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock,
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >
      &&' for 1st argument
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:853:13: note: 
      candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Duration2 =
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 3000000000> >]
            is_convertible<_Duration2, duration>::value
            ^
1 error generated.
L-REMJNAYLOR:poc jnaylor$ g++ -Wall -ggdb -std=gnu++0x -fPIC example.cpp  -c -o example.o
example.cpp:12:9: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
      'time_point<[...], duration<[...], ratio<[...], __static_lcm<ratio<1,
      1000000000>::den, ratio<1001, 30000>::den>::value aka 3000000000>>>' to
      function return type 'time_point<[...], duration<[...], ratio<[...],
      1000000000>>>'
        return ref + NTSC_FPS_t(frames);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:831:28: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, typename
      common_type<duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000000000> >, duration<int,
      ratio<1001, 30000> > >::type>' (aka
      'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, duration<long long,
      ratio<__static_gcd<ratio<1, 1000000000>::num, ratio<1001,
      30000>::num>::value, __static_lcm<ratio<1, 1000000000>::den, ratio<1001,
      30000>::den>::value> > >') to 'const
      std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock,
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >
      &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS time_point
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:831:28: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, typename
      common_type<duration<long long, ratio<1, 1000000000> >, duration<int,
      ratio<1001, 30000> > >::type>' (aka
      'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, duration<long long,
      ratio<__static_gcd<ratio<1, 1000000000>::num, ratio<1001,
      30000>::num>::value, __static_lcm<ratio<1, 1000000000>::den, ratio<1001,
      30000>::den>::value> > >') to
      'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock,
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >
      &&' for 1st argument
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:853:13: note: 
      candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _Duration2 =
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 3000000000> >]
            is_convertible<_Duration2, duration>::value
            ^
1 error generated
```

Comment: The problem is that the return type of the `+` operator is ***not*** the same `time_point`, but [`time_point<C, typename std::common_type<D1, duration<R2,P2>>::type>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/operator_arith2). Basically, you need to express your duration in terms of `std::steady_clock::duration`. You can use `std::duration_cast` for that purpose, but, yes, you'll get rounding errors. No way to avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have identified the issue correctly.  You can use `return time_point_cast<steady_clock::duration>(ref + NTSC_FPS_t(frames));` which will truncate towards zero to the next `steady_clock::duration` (nanosecond).

In C++17, you will have other rounding modes:

- `floor`
- `ceil`
- `round`

You're welcome to use them from here if you want them prior to C++17:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h

If it helps, here is a video tutorial for `<chrono>`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

You could also use ["date.h"](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h) to explore the units that *do* result from `steady_clock::time_point + NTSC_FPS_t` like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1001,30000>> NTSC_FPS_t;

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    auto tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + NTSC_FPS_t{1};
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

For me this just output:

```
4680675375035054[1/3000000000]s
```

Indicating that the sum of `nanoseconds` and `NTSC_FPS_t` has units of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of a nanosecond.

Comment: Thanks for the great link! The most entertaining video I've seen recently that didn't feature Daenerys Targaryen. Now let's find out if my gcc has C++ 17...